# Bootstrap MultiSelect select all gone after appending optgroups and options

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using Bootstrap Multiselect plugin from  http://davidstutz.github.io/ to create an open dropdown. everything is working as it should, except the select all disappears when I append my opt groups and options from my data object.

What do I need to change to get this to show up? I have the Includeselectall configuration set to true.

function initializing:

```
$("#salesfloorMultiSelect").multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
    buttonWidth: 420,
    autoOpen: true,
    beforeclose: function (event, ui){ return false;},
    onChange: function() {
        var fixtureName = $('#salesfloorMultiSelect option:selected');
        var value = fixtureName.val();
        if(value == null) {
            value = 'please';
        }
    }
```

function getting the options:

```
$('#salesfloorMultiSelect').html("");
    $('#salesfloorMultiSelect').append( $('<optgroup>', {
        label: 'all fixtures',
        value: 'all',
    }));
    var reportEntityObj = data.reportEntityObj;
    $.each(reportEntityObj, function(i, e) {
        var roomId = i;
        var optgroup = $('<optgroup/>');
        optgroup.attr('label', roomId.trim());

        $(optgroup).appendTo('#salesfloorMultiSelect');
    });
    $.each(reportEntityObj, function(i, e) {
        var roomId = i;
        $.each(reportEntityObj[roomId], function (index, element) {
            var option = $("<option></option>");
            option.val(element['entityId']);
            option.text(element['entityName']);
            option.appendTo('optgroup[label="' + roomId.trim() + '"]');

            $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: roomId.trim(), value: name }).appendTo('ul.multiselect-item.multiselect-group label');
        });

    });
    $('#salesfloorMultiSelect').multiselect('enable');
    $('#salesfloorMultiSelect').multiselect("rebuild");
```

Can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem as closely as I could, but I cannot reproduce the problem, see https://jsfiddle.net/sw000xa3/. It is hard to tell where the problem is without knowing the data you're putting into the mutliselect as well as seeing the corresponding HTML (e.g. the initial setup before adding the optgroups). Also note that rebuild will remove all HTML from within `ul.multiselect/container`, so adding input's will not work (besides, the element `ul.multiselect-item.multiselect-group` you are referring to does not exist).